# Google Sheets: Formula that returns same number of rows based on cell values

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, repeat, flatten

I have a list of users and a value that denotes how many times I want to return the user's name.

[image]

How do I set up a formula that helps me output this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT(A2:A&"×"; B2:B); "×"))); 
 "where Col1 is not null"; ))
```